# Water dripping onto wallboard outside shower, causing damage

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, shower, tile

I had this bathroom redone in 2015 and the shower does not get used much at all since it is a guest bathroom. The problem I am having is that the wall on the outside of the shower is getting badly damaged because water splashing on the door sits at the bottom of the rubber seal and runs down and out into the corner when he door is opened after a shower. The door has to swing out because the shower is small.

I am realizing now that it should probably have been tiled on the outside when it was done, with the step protruding a little further out and tile on the face going under the step. What you see in the photos is the damage being done from a few angles, and I have knocked out a piece with a screwdriver to make sure the rubber shower pan is wrapping the step.

I'm trying to come up with some way to fix this problem by whatever means necessary, if that means removing portions of existing tile or wallboard. I'm there may be a creative solution to fix his problem. Thank you.

[image: wall damage]
[image: damage from side view]
[image: view from top]

Comment: Hmmm you could replace the wallboard and finish with something suitably water resistant, you could replace the door or sill with something that contains the water better, or you could do both.  Personally I'd look at a door and or sill that retain better, and if that necessitates ripping some wallboard, I'd make sure I replaced it with water resistant stuff because the cost difference is likely a fraction of the value of labor for a re-do.

Comment: Something that might help in the short term, at my parents house we squeegee the bulk of the water off before we get out.  The purpose is to greatly reduce effort to clean, but the side effect is a lot less water dripping off when the door is opened.

Comment: Does the door have a "gutter" on the inside that is sloped from the latch side to the hinge side? That would catch _most_ of the water dripping down the door and channel it back into the shower pan when it's open. Of course, replacing the door (if necessary) is a preventative measure once the current damage is repaired.

Comment: It looks like the installer did not provide a good slope at the threshold, to get the water flowing back into the basin, and used a curved threshold to have it happen more often.  I see your best solution would be to replace the threshold (use one with washboard ridges to collect that extra water) and add a 5 degree tilt inward, and add a toekick (backsplash) in the same material, wider than the opening, to also prevent water damage.    Some will probably get down to your floor regardless, but most will get caught in the threshold to dry out later.

Comment: @BeeKay do you have a link or photo to the curved threshold with ridges and what you mean by backsplash? Also, do you think it's possible to do this in place without much damage to the surrounding tile?

Comment: Rather than ordinary gypsum drywall, waterproof cement board could be used, but the surface of those boards is rough, and needs to be covered for appearance, e.g., with FRP (Fiberglass Reinforced Panels).